# Stretch Image with multi region

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, stretch, uigraphicscontext

I want to set a background image to uiview with multi region like picture below?
How can i do that?

```
       (constant)
        <----->
  +------------------+ ^
  |     |     |      | | (constant)
  |  A  |     |  B   | | 
  |-----+ - - +------| v
  |     |     |      | ^
  |     |     |      | |
  |  C  |     |  D   | | (stretched region)
  |     |     |      | |
  |     |     |      | |
  +------------------+ v
  <—————>     <——————>
   (stretched region)
```

Update: This is my image https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEGP9.png

Comment: Can you explain little bit more that what you want to do. may be by putting a desired output image and some of your code, whatever you have tried till now.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple images for each region.. this will be easier.